# Calculate just based on normal candlestick (pinescript)

Tags: pine-script

Could somebody help me? I want to calculate based on "normal candlestick" opens (although you change to HA, renko, etc. plots must be the same: based in normal candlestick).

Instead of: `myopen = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)`, "D", open), which one should I use?

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use:

```
ticker      = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
realOpen    = security(ticker, timeframe.period, open,   lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

See how it's used in [Backtesting on Non-Standard Charts: Caution! - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/q9laJNG9-Backtesting-on-Non-Standard-Charts-Caution-PineCoders-FAQ/).

#### Warning: This should NOT be used on normal charts, as it will return future values.